# PICKR plugin color picker. Dynamically add input pickers and instantiate each by class, no by ID

Tags: jquery

I use pickr plugin: https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr

In a form where I can dynamically add multiple input fields for the pickers, I don't know how to instantiate each of it. It work only for first. I can't use ID, only classes.

Plugin is built to instantiate single inputs. But my form need to add N. dynamic inputs (unknown quantity)

A jsfiddle where only first is instantiated.

https://jsfiddle.net/dvx79gz1/2/

I actually insert this code in a function called each time a new row is added:

```
var pickr = Pickr.create({
        el: '.picker',
        theme: 'nano', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'
        useAsButton: true,
        comparison: false,
        swatches: [
            'rgb(244, 67, 54)',
            'rgb(233, 30, 99)',
            'rgb(156, 39, 176)',
            'rgb(103, 58, 183)',
            'rgb(63, 81, 181)',
            'rgb(33, 150, 243)',
            'rgb(3, 169, 244)',
            'rgb(0, 188, 212)',
            'rgb(0, 150, 136)',
            'rgb(76, 175, 80)',
            'rgb(139, 195, 74)',
            'rgb(205, 220, 57)',
            'rgb(255, 235, 59)',
            'rgb(255, 193, 7)'
        ],
        defaultRepresentation: 'HEX',
        lockOpacity: true,
        components: {

            // Main components
            preview: true,
            opacity: false,
            hue: true,

            // Input / output Options
            interaction: {
                hex: false,
                rgba: false,
                hsla: false,
                hsva: false,
                cmyk: false,
                input: true,
                clear: true,
                save: true
            }
        },

        strings: {
           save: 'Salva',  // Default for save button
           clear: 'Pulisci', // Default for clear button
           cancel: 'Annulla' // Default for cancel button
        }
    });

    pickr.on('show', (color, instance) => {
        instance.setColor($(instance._root.button).val(), true);
    }).on('save', (color, instance) => {
        $(instance._root.button).val(color.toHEXA().toString());
        instance.hide();
    });
```

I'd like to instantiate in a simple way multiple inputs by class only. no ID.

Anyone use this plugin?

UPDATE: Update fiddle (still not working); https://jsfiddle.net/dvx79gz1/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change selector for each new input, so i added a var outside of new_row function and i incrase it every time the button is clicked and i use it to add a unique class for each input so your code turns into this

```
    var picCounter = 0;

    function new_row() {
       picCounter++;
      //    ADD INPUT

     var newInput = $('<div class="divpicker"><input type="text" class="form-control picker field'+picCounter+'" value="#CCC" name="picker[]"/></div>');

  newInput.appendTo($("#divpickers"));

  //    INIT PICKR


  var newPicker = Pickr.create({
        el: '.field'+picCounter,
        theme: 'nano', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'
        useAsButton: true,
        comparison: false,
        swatches: [
            'rgb(244, 67, 54)',
            'rgb(233, 30, 99)',
            'rgb(156, 39, 176)',
            'rgb(103, 58, 183)',
            'rgb(63, 81, 181)',
            'rgb(33, 150, 243)',
            'rgb(3, 169, 244)',
            'rgb(0, 188, 212)',
            'rgb(0, 150, 136)',
            'rgb(76, 175, 80)',
            'rgb(139, 195, 74)',
            'rgb(205, 220, 57)',
            'rgb(255, 235, 59)',
            'rgb(255, 193, 7)'
        ],
        defaultRepresentation: 'HEX',
        lockOpacity: true,
        components: {

            // Main components
            preview: true,
            opacity: false,
            hue: true,

            // Input / output Options
            interaction: {
                hex: false,
                rgba: false,
                hsla: false,
                hsva: false,
                cmyk: false,
                input: true,
                clear: true,
                save: true
            }
        },

        strings: {
           save: 'Salva',  // Default for save button
           clear: 'Pulisci', // Default for clear button
           cancel: 'Annulla' // Default for cancel button
        }
    });



  newPicker.on('show', (color, instance) => {
        instance.setColor($(instance._root.button).val(), true);
    }).on('save', (color, instance) => {
        $(instance._root.button).val(color.toHEXA().toString());
        instance.hide();
    });

}
```

here the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uyh0L3k9/1/